# Hide modules from TypeScript Language Service autocompletes

Tags: typescript, module

Is there a way to hide module names from TypeScript's Language Service autocompletes?

We have certain modules that we need to be accessible to the type checker, but we don't want them to show up in the autocomplete tooltip when a user types this at the top of a TypeScript file:

`import "`

We are considering using `paths` to name these modules things like `transtive_dependency⚠do_not_import/foo`, but hiding them from autocompletes entirely would be even better.